# Using a dom-repeat in a <table> or <select> breaks on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, polymer, internet-explorer-11, web-component

When working with tables and select dropdowns in Polymer I have found that I can use a dom-repeat template inside of a `<table>`/`<select>` to print out an array of values for the tag. This works flawlessly on all Browsers except for of course Internet Explorer.

Example:

```
<select>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{listOfItems}}" as="item">
    <option value="{{item.value}}">{{item.name}}</option>
  </template>
</select>
```

Another Example straight from the polymer elements catalog:

```
<table id="element-table">
  ...
  <tbody>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[elements]]">
      <tr on-tap="nav" target$="[[item.name]]">
        <td class="name" width="100">[[item.name]]</td>
        <td class="description relative">[[item.description]]</td>
        <td class="tags">
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[item.tags]]">
            <tag-link name="[[item]]" on-tap="tagTapped"></tag-link><span>,</span>
          </template>
        </td>
        <td class="actions">
          <element-action-menu element="[[item.name]]" icons-only=""></element-action-menu>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Is this just not supported in Internet explorer right now (I noticed on the Polymer site that they do not allow IE browsers to visit the table page) or is there a way to do this?

Comment: polymer templates should already be supported in both IE10 and IE11 according to the documentation https://github.com/WebComponents/webcomponentsjs#browser-support maybe its something you should consult them with or perhaps your version of polymer has something to do?

Comment: In their Intro to 1.0 documentation they mention that there are challenges with `<table>` elements and templates, which they are working to overcome: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/#binding-features

Comment: @Zikes, I actually have seen that before but what is interesting is that all of the code above works on every browser except for IE (there goes IE making my life wonderful once again). I am hoping against hope that someone has found a workaround for IE specifically as all the other function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE doesn't have native support for the `<template>` tag and has the additional quirk that it does weird things to non-`<tr>`, `<thead>`, or `<tbody>` tags inside a table and non `<option>` tags inside a select.

Basically the current state is that putting a `dom-repeat` or similar inside a template just blows up the parser in IE and may actually leak out and break other parts of an application beyond just the table rendering.

The Polymer team is [definitely aware of this issue](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#template-repeat) but (as of 2016-04-01) there are no official workarounds.

You could try to fake a table using CSS `display: table`.  It's an ugly hack, but IE isn't giving much of an option.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me really appreciate it. So if IE doesn't have native support for the `<template>` tag isn't that something that should be polyfilled by webcomponents.js (or the lite version)?

Comment: Yes, and it is (successfully) in almost all cases. But, as I mentioned, the IE element parser does weird things to tags inside of `table` and `select` that aren't the "approved" tags to go inside of it. This means that the polyfill is unable to find and successfully manage the nodes because IE's parser isn't handling them like normal elements.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks so much for your help. I think I will probably go implement my own `<element-table>` tag and run with that.